# What is the meaning of the little colored boxes (badges) on avatars in Trello?

Tags: trello

My avatars have little little colored boxes in the lower right corners, sometimes yellow or green.  Under the Members list I also have a blue box - I guessed this was an "owner" indicator.

I didn't see anything about these in the documentation.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[image: user icons in trello]

If you hover your mouse over the little boxes, you'll see the following tooltips:

**Blue:** "This member is an **owner** of this board" (or organization)

**Green:** "This member is **online** and viewing Trello"
**Yellow:** "This member is **idle**.  They have Trello open but are not looking at it"
**Gray:** "This member is **offline**"

So in the image above, top left user is active.  Top right users is an owner, and is idle (or away).  And the two users on the bottom are board members who are not currently logged on to Trello (inactive).

Comment: Will this information get added to the blog or the documentation at some point? It's one of the first things a new user would ask, but there's nothing in the UI that would answer it. Even clicking on the user's avatar doesn't give an explanation -- in fact, the color chips aren't even shown in the resulting pop-up.

Comment: @JoeWhite you should see an explanation when you hover over them, right?

Comment: All I see on hover is the persons name appear, no explanation of the coloured boxes.

Comment: @MichaelPryor: Why would I hover over the little color chips when they're part of a larger icon? I just hover over the icon they're part of, which only tells me the user's name. And when I click that icon looking for an explanation, the color chips go away! And no, most of them don't show any explanation -- gray, nothing; green, nothing. If I *happen* to hover directly over the tiny purple color chip as my first attempt to answer the "WTF are these?" question, then yes, I would happen to get a very limited answer. But you leave most of my routes of investigation as dead ends.

Comment: On my PC, using Chrome, only the blue "owner" box appears to have a tooltip.

Comment: FWIW, trello now has tooltips for all of the status indicators