# Trello - what is the purple chevron?

Tags: trello, trello-cards

Recently on Trello I'm seeing a purple-coloured chevron pointing up in the bottom-left corner of some members icons on the cards.

[image: Purple chevron member icon]

Does anyone know what this purple chevron represents?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's meant to indicate that the member is the board/organization admin.

Previously this was [indicated by a blue square/circle](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19004/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-little-colored-boxes-badges-on-avatars-in-trello).

Comment: There really should be a little key for these coloured shapes.

Comment: @Steb Believe it or not, the alt text for the little chevron tries to explain what it means ... if you manage to get your cursor on top of it.

Comment: Doh! Can't believe I missed that!